# Did Lord Kelvin say "If you can not measure it, you can not improve it"?

Tags: quotes, productivity, management

[AZquotes](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/791855) claims that Lord Kelvin (or William Thomson) said this:

> If you can not measure it, you can not improve it.

[image]

But there is no such a quote in [his Wikiquote page](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/William_Thomson). So did he actually say this?

Comment: I haven’t checked whether other sources repeat this claim, but that doesn’t seem sufficiently notable.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm how do you define sufficiently notable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He didn't say that exact quote; Lord Kelvin tended towards rambling, so if you see any particularly pithy one-liner quotes, it probably wasn't him. [His actual quote?](https://archive.org/stream/popularlecturesa01kelvuoft#page/72)

> I often say that when you can measure what you are speaking about, and
>   express it in numbers, you know something about it; but when you
>   cannot measure it, when you cannot express it in numbers, your
>   knowledge is of a meagre and unsatisfactory kind; it may be the
>   beginning of knowledge, but you have scarcely, in your thoughts,
>   advanced to the stage of science, whatever the matter may be.

The actual source is from Antoine-Augustin Cournot, in De l’origine et des limites de la correspondance entre l’algèbre et la géométrie (1847), 375.

Comment: how did you find the source?

Answer (score -5):

At [here](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780191826719.001.0001/q-oro-ed4-00006236) I found that:

> When you can measure what you are speaking about, and express it in
> numbers, you know something about it; but when you cannot measure it,
> when you cannot express it in numbers, your knowledge is of a meagre
> and unsatisfactory kind: it may be the beginning of knowledge, but you
> have scarcely, in your thoughts, advanced to the stage of science,
> whatever the matter may be.
> **often quoted as ‘If you cannot measure it, then it is not science’** Popular Lectures and Addresses vol. 1 (1889) ‘Electrical Units of
> Measurement’, delivered 3 May 1883

Comment: This is the same quote provided in the accepted answer from 2018. Please make sure that you're not duplicating answers that have already been provided.

Comment: Although it is the same as the accepted answer has already, I would like to clarify that I found the earliest explanation of the quote on the webpage.